# Sci-fi B-movie about creatures that take over humans by going through their mouths

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a campy English b-movie that I saw on TV a few years ago. I believe the setting is an underwater base. The creatures have long bodies with tiny hands
and one of the crew is an android. Someone in it might be named Pickett.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Was it in English?

Comment: yes its an english movie, saw it on tv years ago, just stuck in my mind

Comment: "English movie" as in "the characters spoke English" or as in "I'm reasonably sure the movie was a production from England/United Kingdom"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you may be looking for the 1995 TV movie *[The Alien Within](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114795/?ref_=tt_urv)*, also released as *Unknown Origin*

> Crew of an undersea mining platform falls prey to mysterious and dangerous parasite. The parasite has the ability to affect people's minds, so survivors can't be certain who is safe and who is infected.

Alex Hyde-White plays Jedidiah Pickett.

### Trailer

Found with a search for `film "underwater base" "android" mouth`

Comment: YOU FOUND IT!!!!!